# Does Graph Engine Have a Persistance Layer

Tags: graphengine

I'm looking into GraphEngine for some heavy workloads. I would like to persist the data for future analysis and in case of server reboot. Looking at the documentation both CloudStorage and LocalStotage actually just persist to ram. Is it possible to persist to an extensible storage interface?

Answer (score 1):

Global.CloudStorage.SaveStorage() or Global.LocalStorage.SaveStorage() will save the memory contents to the disk. Global.CloudStorage.LoadStorage() will command all servers to read it back into memory.

[Link to CloudStorage API](http://www.graphengine.io/APIRefs/html/T_Trinity_Storage_MemoryCloud.htm)